# Requests SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.recruit.com.hk', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm getting really confused over this.

Here's what I'm using.

- requests 2.18.4
- python 2.7.14

I'm building a scraper and trying to use `requests.get()` to connect to a url.

This is a link from indeed that jumps to another link.
Here is the code:

```
r = rqs.get('https://www.indeed.hk/rc/clk?jk=ab794b2879313f04&fccid=a659206a7e1afa15')
```

Here's the error raised:

```
File "/Users/cecilialee/anaconda/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 506, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.recruit.com.hk', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /jobseeker/JobDetail.aspx?jobOrder=L04146652 (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, u'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:661)'),))
```

Setting `verify = False` does not solve this error.

I've searched online but couldn't find a solution that can help to fix my issue. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

You can use HTTP (but not https) to get info from the site.

```
>>> response = requests.get('http://www.recruit.com.hk')
>>> response.status_code
200
>>> len(response.text)
```

I tried you code, it's ok:

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://www.indeed.hk/rc/clk?jk=ab794b2879313f04&fccid=a659206a7e1afa15')
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> len(r.text)
34272
```

My environment:

python 2.7.10
requests==2.5.0